# Food safe water proofing finish?

Tags: finishing

I'm looking to build a vertical farm for practical and decorative purposes. It would be a tube design where I pump water to the top and it would trickle down along the sides of the tube, watering the little holes with plants along the way. Since I want to build it out of whats cheaply available here (mystery planks, probably pine or spruce) and my previous experience with exposing that stuff to water, I'd need to waterproof it somehow. Since the plants that would grow there would be edible, it should also be free from chemicals that could leach into the plants and then into the food.

What kind of finish could I use on the inside of the tube to prevent the water from destroying it?

Comment: There's no standard definition of "food safe", so you're likely to get a lot of conflicting opinions about that.  I personally believe that any properly-cured finish will be food safe.  However on the "water proof" side of the question (continuous total submersion) I really only see one option...a 2-part marine epoxy.

Comment: Honestly, don't use wood for this. Except maybe as a cache-pot or decorative surround.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Food safe and weather/rot resistance](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/6449/food-safe-and-weather-rot-resistance)

Comment: There are many, many previous Q&A for waterproofing wood. I'm voting to close this one in favour of an obvious one.

Comment: @jdv While I definitely don't want to have this conversation again (and I'll back up your vote to close) I actually think that those two are slightly different as the other one is exposed to the weather while this one is continuously submerged.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 If it makes a difference, the wood wouldn't be submerged the entire time but rather for 1 minute at a time in 5 minute intervals so constantly wet at the least.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 I see this more as wood surfaces that are to be exposed to constant wet over their lifetimes. It is this wet-dry pattern that is the challenge in both cases. In that respect, the linked Q&A, among others, covers what needs to be covered. We are talking about epoxy or typical oil-based "spar" finish, often reapplied regularly.

Comment: Here's the thing, you want to use a cheap wood for this and you're then have to apply a really good waterproofing to it, where **all** options in this area are, um, not inexpensive. You'll be ahead of the game if you just plump for better material to begin with. And quite apart from the fact that it's *very* likely to cost you less — expect some sticker shock on good epoxies and marine varnishes! — you sidestep the concerns about the 'food safe' thing. Even though those worries are basically unfounded you worry about what you worry about and often nobody can convince you otherwise.